# Why is Angular JSON coming in as a ListBuffer? (And how to parse...)

Tags: json, angularjs, scala, parsing, playframework-2.0

*Edit* I initially described this wrong -- rewritten below.

For some reason, I cannot get Angular to send the JSON payload in a way that it is interpreted as a simple string.  Looking at the [JsObject](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-SNAPSHOT/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject) body, it is always a `ListBuffer` for some unknown reason.

## Code

### Application.scala

(Taking from [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonHttp))

```
  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "language").read[Int]
    )((name: String, languageId: Int) => User(None, name, languageId))

  def submitUser = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) {
    implicit request =>
      val userResult = request.body.validate[User]
      userResult.fold(
        errors => {
          BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
        },
        user => {
          userDao.add(user)
          Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK", "message" -> ("User '" + user.full_name + "' saved.")))
        }
      )
  }
```

### User.scala

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], full_name: String, language: Int)
```

### app.js

*(Only relevant piece)*

```
$scope.submit = function(event) {
    $scope.loadingTracker = promiseTracker();
    return $http.post('/user', {
        data: {name: 'Joe Blow', language: 1}
    }, { tracker: $scope.loadingTracker })
      .success(function(id) {
          console.log("Success! Created user with id " + id);
      });
}
```

(I have tried using `JSON.stringify`, etc.)

## Exception

Doing the traditional "Reads" on this gives me this error, or something similar:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:64) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:64) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:71) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:10) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.as(JsValue.scala:62) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JsObject.as(JsValue.scala:164) ~[play-json_2.10-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
```

Because the data looks like this:

`> body = {play.api.libs.json.JsObject@14793} {"data":{"name":"Joe Blow","language":1}}` and "JsObject" has a member `fields` which is a ListBuffer (in this case, size = 1)

I know this is a totally "noob" question but **I don't know how to read the `ListBuffer` from the body, let alone parse it into the case class**.  I would like to just parse this whatever way is most proper; it makes no sense to me why this simple JSON is being turned into a ListBuffer by Play.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Leaving my buggy version for context; fix was to remove the "data:" part in the JavaScript, leaving with "{ name: 'Joe Blow', 'language': 1}, { tracker: $scope.loadingTracker })".  "data" is implied in this signature (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).)

Comment: Also wanted to add that it appears it _should_ be a `ListBuffer`, with each key/value pair as a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your searching for data in the right place.

```
(JsPath \ "name")
```

lets me think that you're skipping the "data" level in your JSON data structure. You may try to add

```
(JsPath \ "data" \ "name")
```

and see if things get better. Moreover, you may try to define your Reads directly defining a implicit format this way :

```
 Json.format[User]
```

and then read your data as you're already doing :

```
val placeResult = request.body.validate[User]
```

These are just some hints, I'm not a JSON nor a scala expert and I haven't tried the code...

Comment: Good lord.  I was up until 3am last night trying to get something related to this working (specifically where you see the `=> User` part in the reader) and I think some of the debility and stupidity seeped into this morning.  The "data" part was part of the JSON because I am using the shorthand method of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).